# Html tags are showing on frontend in custom module textarea admin form field?

Tags: adminhtml, adminform, wysiwyg, magento2.3.2, editor

I am using [Testimonial](https://www.yereone.com/testimonials-extension-for-magento-2) extension which has textarea field in admin form.

When I am adding content with html tag, html tags are showing on frontend.

I have tried to change textarea to editor from block file but still it is not working.

Content field code in block file is:

```
$generalFieldset->addField(
            'testimonial_content',
            'editor',
            [
                'label'    => __('Testimonial Content'),
                'title'    => __('Testimonial Content'),
                'class'    => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name'     => 'testimonial_content',
                'value'    => $this->testimonial,
                'config'    => $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(),
                'wysiwyg'   => true,
            ]
        );
```

What is the issue? can anyone suggest?

Comment: Can you share the screen-sort, what you are added from admin and how it show on frontend? And also share the code which you done for display value?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, Please check screenshots: Frontend:  https://nimb.ws/CJ3LD9 ,    

Admin:   https://nimb.ws/dhvYtH